# How can I show dynamically "nested" objects with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a Object with dynamic content, for example:

```
$scope.test = [
{
   "name" : "device1",
   "params" : [{"freq1" : "144"},{"freq2" : "160"}]

},
{
   "name" : "device2",
   "params" : [{"freq3" : "144"}]

}]
```

I use ng-repeat to show the content:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in test">{{key}}:{{value}}<li>
```

But how can i use key value for params?

```
<li ng-repeat="(k,v) in test.params">{{k}}:{{v}}<li>
```

isn't working :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/kyGa3/1/

Edit:

```
$scope.test = [
{
   "name" : "device1",
   "params" : [{"freq1" : "144"},{"freq2" : "160"}],
   "category" : "test-category"

},
{
   "name" : "device2",
   "params" : [{"freq3" : "144"}],
   "vendor" : "intel"

}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to add another level of `ng-repeat`to iterate display the `test.params`' individual keys and values - here's a modified version of your fiddle:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
        {{value.name}}
        <ul ng-repeat="(k, v) in value.params">
            <li ng-repeat="(paramKey, paramVal) in v">{{paramKey}} -&gt; {{paramVal}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

This will output:

- device1

  - freq1 -> 144
  - freq2 -> 160
- device2

  - freq3 -> 144

Also please note that your fiddle is missing the square brackets to turn `$scope.test`into an array

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to browse the hole array/object automatically? Because i dont know the key, they are dynamic ...see start post please. http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/kyGa3/4/

Comment: here is a example, hope you understand me :-) http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/kyGa3/5/

Comment: Ah I see, wasn't quite obvious to me from your first example :) - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/D9MAB/
Note that I up'ed angularjs' version to 1.2 to use ng-if (you could do it with `ng-show`too though.
To check if we have to iterate over a value we add a `$scope.isArray` method to the controller

Comment: You are my hero! Never used ng-repeat this way! haha

Answer (score 1):

calling function from template.
**html:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in device">
    <td><strong>{{key}}</strong></td>
    <td>{{val(value)}}</td>
</tr>
```

**js**

```
    $scope.val = function(value) {
        if(typeof value == 'string') {return value}
        else if(typeof value == "object") {
            var values="";
            value.forEach(function(val,index){

                if(val.name) {values+=val.name}
                else if(val.freq) {values+=val.freq+", "}
                 else if(val.maxFreq) {values+=val.maxFreq+", "}
            });
            return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I am searching for. Is there a way to add them without know there names (maxFreq,freq,...)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/kyGa3/2/

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="projects"> 

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in device">
            <td><strong>{{key}}</strong></td>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
        <div ng-repeat="item in device.params">
            <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in item">
                <strong>{{ k }}</strong>
                {{ v }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

device.params is array...

Comment: Thank you! How can I nest them under the params key?